# Function takes long time for execution

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

Actually, I am trying to find out wheather the partno is existing in the database table or not and it takes long time in  count = checkCommand.ExecuteReader sataement

Please find the method below

```
Public Function CheckProductNo(ByVal Partno As String) As Boolean
    Dim count As SqlDataReader
    Dim valid As Boolean = False
    Using connection As New SqlConnection
         connection.Open()
        Using checkCommand As New SqlCommand("PartNo_check", connection)

            checkCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            checkCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@PartNo", Partno))
            count = checkCommand.ExecuteReader
            If count.ToString > 0 Then
                valid = True
            End If
        End Using

    End Using
    Return valid

End Function


STORED PROCEDURE
CREATE PROCEDURE PartNo_Check
@PartNo VARCHAR(30)

AS

SELECT PartNo from T_Product where PartNo=@Partno

Thanks
```

Comment: What is the code for `"PartNo_check"` stored procedure? And why do you use SqlDataReader.ToString()

Comment: Please find the stored procedure, Well the problem is in checkcommad.executeredaer, i havenot got chance to see further and doing random experiments

Comment: How many row to you have in T_Product? If it's huge, you might want to think of adding an index on PartNo

Answer (score 1):

It's important to be specific about what your code is supposed to do - looks to me like you're trying to determine if something exists, rather than its count or some other attribute.  Towards that, I would modify your sproc as follows:

```
STORED PROCEDURE
CREATE PROCEDURE PartNo_Check
@PartNo VARCHAR(30)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT PartNo 
                           FROM     T_Product
                           where PartNo=@Partno) THEN 1
             ELSE 0
        END
```

Theoretically that should perform the best for what you're trying to do, and you should ensure there's an index on the ParNo column, as called out by Steve.  Your method could then be written as:

```
 Public Function CheckProductNo(ByVal Partno As String) As Boolean
   Using connection As New SqlConnection
     connection.Open()
    Using checkCommand As New SqlCommand("PartNo_check", connection)
        checkCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        checkCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@PartNo", Partno))
        return convert.toboolean(checkCommand.executescalar)
    End Using

End Using

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your PartNo_check returns only a single numeric value, then try to use

```
Dim result As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(checkCommand.ExecuteScalar())
```

With the stored procedure code given then use

```
Dim result As String = checkCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
```

If your stored procedure returns only one row with one column the ExecuteScalar take that unique result as its return value. Additional columns or rows are ignored

[See MSDN references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx#Y0)

Comment: hi steve , Sorry to say . It does not make any difference , I tried both

Comment: Do you have an index on that PartNo field? And the slowness is only on this particular operation or is more generalized?

Comment: Its only for this operation , basically i am storing computed values like that 2020-2322

Comment: I think that to squeeze every bit of performance you need an index on that column

Comment: that will throw a null reference exception is there isn't a matching record in the table

Comment: @JimMcKeon you are right. The OP need to change the stored procedure with something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM X WHERE F=Y`

Answer (score 0):

I would try and debug the problem from the bottom up; You can check if the stored procedure is taking too much time, by querying it in SQL management tool of some kind.

If that is the case, my first resolution would be to optimize the database, check your indexes etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to acknowledge if there is data for Partno then I suggest you to modify your query to :

```
STORED PROCEDURE
CREATE PROCEDURE PartNo_Check
@PartNo VARCHAR(30)

AS

SELECT Top 1 PartNo from T_Product where PartNo=@Partno
```

then you will have to

```
count = checkCommand.ExecuteReader
If count.HasRow then valid=true
```

this is for your problem then, but if you want to manipulate any data related, this would not be a good solution.

Hope this works as fast as you wish!